# String manipulation error in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Actually i want to replace the whole word in the sentence. but this contains and replace function replacing the sub string

for eg : A man  with a {unpleasant woman |disagreeable woman}

I want to replace only this whole word man... not woman
Please help me...
Thanks in advance !

```
if(Init.SpintexEditorPropertyMain.SpinContent.Contains(spinkey) && spinkey != string.Empty)
{
       Init.SpintexEditorPropertyMain.SpinContent = Init.SpintexEditorPropertyMain.SpinContent.Replace(spinkey, spinvalue);
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: have you looked at any of the links on the right of this page under the `RELATED` section, there are what appears to be several links that may lead you to the answer you are seeking. show some more effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with regex

```
        string input = "A man with a {unpleasant woman |disagreeable woman}";
        string output =  Regex.Replace(input, @"\bman\b", "abc");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

\b stands for word boundries.

Answer (score 2):

try adding a blank before "man" resulting in " man" :) and use this for replace. It will not be found in "woman" .

Comment: not an answer.. and why would he manually want to add a space or a blank.. you would not make a good coder based on that answer which `IS NOT AN ANSWER`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE; because he actually wants to replace " man" not "man". It IS an answer.

Comment: Why don't you think it's an answer?

Comment: What if he had the word `man` in a file for example 1000 times? I am quite aware that you could add a space manually .. lets say the OP does not have access to a file that he is reading in regards to modifying the file..? then what would he do..??

Comment: The OP says he wants to replace the whole word. Just adding a space in front would still match any word beginning with man.

Comment: @George87, your answer addresses the question: "How do I add a sentinel token after the word 'man' so that I can operate on it?" But this wasn't the OP's question.  But you got some rep out of it, so all's well.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

```
string a = "A man with a {unpleasant woman |disagreeable woman}";
string b = @"\bman\b";
string c = "men";
string str = Regex.Replace(a, b, c);
```

\b used for word boundaries